# CakePHP validate fields that aren't in the Database

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I have a form with values that aren't in my database. I do wan't validation on them so I made some validation rules using the field names. Somehow the validation rules aren't being used.

I already tried to set different rules. The file names are correct since the $hasMany connection works.

I hope you can help!

Form:

```
<?php
  echo $this->Form->create('Map');
    echo $this->Form->input('min_x');
    echo $this->Form->input('max_x');
    echo $this->Form->input('min_y');
    echo $this->Form->input('max_y');
  echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

Validation rules:

```
public $validate = array(
  'min_x' => array(
    'rule' => 'Numeric',
    'message' => 'Please enter a numeric value.'
  ),
  'max_x' => array(
    'rule' => 'Numeric',
    'message' => 'Please enter a numeric value.'
  ),
  'min_y' => array(
    'rule' => 'Numeric',
    'message' => 'Please enter a numeric value.'
  ),
  'max_y' => array(
    'rule' => 'Numeric',
    'message' => 'Please enter a numeric value.'
  ),
);
```

Comment: what class and file name is `$validate` in?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Good question, it should be in the `Map` model.

Comment: As stated before it is in the correct file. Its in the Map.php file in the Model Folder. The class is: class Map extends AppModel

Comment: Actually, nevermind that: is the rule case sensitive? `'rule' => 'Numeric'` to `'rule' => 'numeric'`

Comment: They are case sensitive.

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint but it isn't working :-(

Answer (score 0):

Rules for validation are case sensitive, so:

```
'rule' => 'Numeric',
```

should be changed to

```
'rule' => 'numeric',
```

for each instance.

You also have an extra comma on the last field's array.

---

```
public $validate = array(
  'min_x' => array(
    'numeric' => array(
        'rule' => 'numeric',
        'message' => 'Please enter a numeric value.'
    )
  ),
  'max_x' => array(
    'numeric' => array(
        'rule' => 'numeric',
        'message' => 'Please enter a numeric value.'
    )
  ),
  'min_y' => array(
    'numeric' => array(
        'rule' => 'numeric',
        'message' => 'Please enter a numeric value.'
    )
  ),
  'max_y' => array(
    'numeric' => array(
        'rule' => 'numeric',
        'message' => 'Please enter a numeric value.'
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Are you sure nothing else was changed between when you had a working `$hasMany` and now? It sounds like $validate is being ignored

Comment: I'm sure I just did a query and the $hasMany was used.

Comment: one more attempt: try the code in my edit. I removed an extra comma at the end and reformatted the rule

Comment: @Ryflex the more I think about it, the more I'm pretty sure there was a supressed syntax error causing the issue. The extra comma probably stopped the actual validation result from being returned.

Comment: I removed the extra comma, stupid I overlooked it but unfortunatly it isn't the problem. Tried your version as well and same result.

Comment: I also added 'rule' => 'notEmpty' to check if the required asterisk would appear and it didn't

Comment: Ok somehow it seems to be going wrong on the fact that the fieldname isn't in the database. I adjusted the name of one of the fields and validation to a databasefield name and suddenly it's being accepted. According to documentation it should still work if the field is not in the database.

Comment: That's actually incorrect: see [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Data-Validation.html) - "Assuming that the users **table** has login, password, email and born fields"

Answer (score 0):

At the end of all the messages there must be ','.

```
'max_x' => array(
    'numeric' => array(
        'rule' => 'numeric',
        'message' => 'Please enter a numeric value.',
    )
  ),
```